# How do you not override other angular directives when using isolate scope and still being able to call methods in the scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an anchor tag that I wish to hide or show depending on a value in the model.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>Other Stuff</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#/somewhere" ng-show="model.showIt" myCustomDir="some value" onClick="bar(item)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now in my directive I have the following:

```
app.directive('myCustomDir', function() {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            onClick: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var hover = angular.element("<div><b>Some Text</b></div>");
            var button = hover.find('b');

            button.on('click', function() {
               scope.$apply(function() {
                   scope.onClick();
               })
            });
        }
    };

    return def;
})
```

The problem is as soon as I include my directive the ng-show one I think no longer works and that is because if I am correct it is because my directive works in isolate scope so the model from the parent scope is no longer present.

How would I get my directive to play nicely with ng-show while still being able to let someone what method they want to call when the  tag is clicked.

Plunker for all those interested. http://plnkr.co/edit/BLMCgB

Comment: onClick: "@" is incorrect.  If you want to execute an expression in the parent scope, use "&" instead - see here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @Mark, yes sorry I keep doing that. I have the correct version in my actual code. Updating the question now.

Answer (score 2):

You directive creates an isolated scope. So you need to use `$parent` to get the value of the current repeater item

```
ng-show="$parent.item.visible"
```

If you want to make it more generic, you can take the scope off to make it compatible with other directives. Then you can use `scope.$eval` to call the function passed in.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($document) {
    var definition = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {

                ...

                button.on('click', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.onClick);
                        hover.remove();
                    })
                });
            });
        }
    }

    return definition;
})
```

Comment: I know it is creating an isolate scope :( Hence my question about how do you not override other angular directives when creating an isolate scope. I see now that I could get my view to work by using the $parent but that feels aweful. So if i write a directive for someone else then they have to know that the directive creates an isolate scope. Just doesn't feel right.

Comment: @uriDium Why do you feel it aweful? You directive does not override other directive at all. It depends on you whether you want make your directive to be compatible with other directive. Does it make sense? It is you determine whether you want other people's directive to use together with your directive or not.

Comment: Like I said in my comment. If I gave this directive to someone else to use, they would have to have initiate knowledge of the directive (i.e. go digging in its source) to know that they should now be using $parent.item in other directives that they may want to use. So by adding my directive I break their views. That is why I said it feels awful.

Comment: @uriDium If you want your directive to be compatible with other directives, Remove that `scope{}`. That's all.

Comment: but then I lose the ability to let the person using my directive  set the expression (might be scope function) that happens when the user clicks the button. Maybe I am trying to be too clever here. Maybe I should just expect that if they want a callback they must use the attribute ok-click.

Comment: @uriDium you are not too clever. You are just too nice. You can take a look at the angularjs directives and you will see most of them don't have `scope` defined, which doesn't create a isolated scope. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ng/directive

Answer (score 0):

If you want allow any global directive - don't declare private scope.
If you want allow only few directives, add links in scope declaration:

```
scope: {
            onClick: "&",
            ngShow : "&"
        },
```

To your question in comments:
Declare controller in directive and declare method in this controller. Then in directive template assign ng-click to this method.

```
var def = {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.callMe = function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  }
}
```

in template:

```
<div ng-click="callMe()">content</div>
```

This method will be accessible only inside your directive.

Comment: I would ideally like to be able to allow ANY global directive. But how  can I achieve that and still let someone else using my directive what method he wants executed when using my directive?

Comment: just remove `scope` declaration.

Comment: But then how do I know what to execute on the button click? I don't want to force the person using my directive to have to have a specific function in his scope. I would prefer him to be able to tell me what function to execute. Maybe there is something that I just don't understand.

Comment: I followed your example in the meantime specifying the ngShow as you did but that did not work. All my elements in the repeat remain hidden regardless of the value.

Comment: I don't see your jsfiddle/plunker so I can't say what is wrong with particular code.

Comment: Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BLMCgB. If I add ng-show="item.visible" it stops working.

Comment: Because your directive has private scope and there is no 'item' in that scope. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uxzwf6 - onBar moved to directive, scope of directive now is global (since you want access `item` model). `scope.onClick()` string because there is no such method in scope.

Comment: I think you missed what I was trying to do. I was trying to create a little popup, when you click on the link in the table it opens a little popup with a button. When you click the button in the popup it calls an expression that is specified in the view (may be a function in the scope) and then hides the pop up again.